# WordPress Shortcode Displays HTML Incorrectly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

I'm a webmaster for a local volunteer history group, and as such I've built a WordPress theme and I'm trying to make it easy for other volunteers to maintain/work with. I've made an easy to follow 'template' for adding buttons, and I decided to take it the extra step and make a shortcode for anyone who doesn't know HTML.

```
<div class="button-container" id="bkg-img">
  <a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn-clear">
    <h2 class="button">Button Title</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

The above produces this...
https://mattyoungdesigns.com/img/Correct%20Button.png

My shortcode is built as follows...

```
//Button Shortcode
function button_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        title => 'This is a button',
        background => '',
        src => '#',
        target => '',
    ), $atts
);

$displaybutton = '<div class="button-container" id="' . $atts[ 'background' ] . '>';
$displaybutton .= '<a href="' . $atts[ 'src' ] . '" class="btn-clear" target="' . $atts[ 'target' ] . '" style="margin-top: 25px;">';
$displaybutton .= '<h2 class="button">';
$displaybutton .= $atts[ 'title' ];
$displaybutton .= '</h2></a></div>';


return $displaybutton;

}

// Register Shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'button', 'button_shortcode' );
```

And it outputs...
https://mattyoungdesigns.com/img/Incorrect%20Button.png

I'm new to making shortcodes so I'm sure it's probably just something I'm missing, but why does the shortcode display differently than just the HTML?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Try using this.  Also, I think you were missing a double quote in your output which could be causing it to render poorly.

```
//Button Shortcode
function button_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {

$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        title => 'This is a button',
        background => '',
        src => '#',
        target => '',
    ), $atts
);

return '<span class="' . esc_attr($a['class']) . '">' . $content . '</span>';

$displaybutton '<div class="button-container" id="' . esc_attr($atts[ 'background' ]) . '">';
$displaybutton .= '<a href="' . esc_attr($atts[ 'src' ]) . '" class="btn-clear" target="' . esc_attr($atts[ 'target' ]) . '" style="margin-top: 25px;">';
$displaybutton .= '<h2 class="button">';
$displaybutton .= esc_attr($atts[ 'title' ]);
$displaybutton .= '</h2></a></div>';

return $displaybutton;

}

// Register Shortcodes
add_shortcode( 'button', 'button_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Oops! That was remnant from where I was trying to fix the problem. The btn-container was displaying about 25px downward from the anchor tag. Margin-top works on larger displays but when I get into mobile size it breaks...After looking at it further, I think part of it is due to WordPress. It seems to put to unecessary paragraph tags in between the elements inside the div. I found that in my browser inspector, but even removing the paragraph tags didn't fix it. I can't help but feel they're somehow related though.

Comment: Updated per your comments, try that.